# How to prevent "NucleusDataStoreException: Concurrent Modification"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Our app suddenly got a lot of traffic and there were some design flaws in the system (or rather we never thought it would get this much traffic so we just skipped it by choice).

As the topic states I'm looking for a way to prevent the error: `org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Concurrent Modification`

Currently I have an entity called `Group` that looks like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Group extends PersistableString {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6215353466976945628L;

    @Persistent
    private int yesCount;
    @Persistent
    private int noCount;

    public void increaseYesCount()
    {
        yesCount++;
    }
    public void increaseNoCount()
    {
        noCount++;
    }
}
```

The following code is how the update of the entity is done:

```
int answer = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("answer"))

try {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
    for(String groupId : allGroupsToBeUpdated)
    {
        Group group = pm.getObjectById(Group.class, groupId);
        if(answer == 0)
            group.increaseNoCount();
        else
            group.increaseYesCount();
    }
    pm.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`allGroupsToBeUpdated` is a list that contains around 30 string-ids. Is there some way I can avoid the `Concurrent Modification`-error? Can I check if the entity that I retrieve is being updated and then just discard(/ignore) the update? It's not SUPER important that the write actually succeeds, I just wanna make sure I don't get the error (or that it keeps trying to succeed with the write), because it's causing the request to take between 10-30seconds.

Should I maybe open (get new `PM-instance`) and close the connection (`pm.close()`) between each update instead of waiting for all of the 30ish updates to go through?

I know of sharded counters and should have (obviously) used them, but right now I'm looking for a "quick-fix" to this problem.

EDIT:
I'm using:

```
App Engine SDK 1.8.9

JDO 3.0
```

Stacktrace can be found at:
http://pastebin.com/TWnmkpPU

Comment: since you don't post the stack trace, versions of software, its impossible to say anything.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think this was relevant. The problem is (atleast I think it is) that this request is ran on multple server instances and the same Group that wants to get updated and thus causing the error. I will update the post with App engine versions and possibly a stacktrace.

Comment: So the concurrent modification exception is thrown by Google's database and/or handling code (i.e nothing to do with JDO as such). Maybe upgrade what version of libraries are being used (JDO v2 is ancient, for example), maybe use transactions in your code

Comment: Sorry my bad! I'm using JDO v3. "Switch to JDO 3.0 by selecting Datanucleus JDO/JPA v2", that's the number I saw and wrote, but it's in fact JDO 3.0. Yah, maybe upgrading the App Engine SDK will make a difference, but I'm sceptical that's the issue. When the server is uploaded I think it uses the latest "engine" behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer due to length.

Transactions probably aren't good in your case since you are really just looking to hide the issue from the user which is manifesting itself in slow request times. Perhaps kicking off an async push task to do the writes in the background outside of the request would be your best bet.

I really would not recommend design based on hiding errors and swallowing exceptions though. Looking to "prevent" an exception that is doing what it is supposed to (signaling a failed write due to contention), means you should avoid the condition which caused it in the first place.

I totally understand needing to get things working fast early on, but it may be a good idea to start adopting best practices now once the bad design decisions just start making their mark. Continuing to rely on "quick-fixes" and hiding problems can land you in a real mess later on.

Comment: Thanks for your input regarding this! Of course I wouldn't want this solution long-term. But implementing sharding with the current time at hand is a too big of a time-investment. I believe the long request time is due to the exception and the write operation is "on-hold" because it wants to write, but can't. A successful request of this type take less then 1 seconds to perform, which is why I think a push task would only move the problem.

Comment: No problem. Yes, a task would only move the problem however this would be a quick-fix to ensure that the problem is hidden from the user. You are right about why the write operation is waiting due to contention, but because the operation is synchronous your code is going to block on the delay. AFAIK there is no way to just make JDO "fail fast" on concurrent modification (probably with good reason).